# Change style on a row in JQuery Datatables when editing displayed values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-3, datatable

I have a datatable from the JQuery plugin that displayes objects fetched from a database. At the end of each row there is an "edit" button that when clicked opens up a popup with fields that allows the user to change the object.

The code below is the "edit" button opening the popup.

```
<td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Edit",
                                 "controllerMethodReturningEditView",
                                 new
                                 {
                                     Id = @m.Id
                                 },
                                 new AjaxOptions
                                 {
                                     HttpMethod = "GET",
                                     UpdateTargetId = "popupBox",
                                     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                     OnSuccess = "openPopup('myPopup')"
                                 })</td>
```

The controller method called when pressing the edit button just opens a view that is a partial displayed in a popupbox

```
return PartialView("editObjectView", objectModel);
```

and this "editObjectView" just contains a form with fields for taking input.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(...
           <label>...</label><input ... />
           .... and so on
```

Then in this popup the user is allowed to edit the values of the displayed object. When the user presses a "save" button in the popup the new values will be sent to a controller method that saves the values (to the object) in the database. When the values are saved the controller method calls the controller method that loaded the first view (the view showing the datatable) and that method requests all objects from the database in order to display new objects or changes to objects.

Now here is my question: when the page is reloaded after an object has been edited, how do I change the style of the edited row? All I want is to set a red border around the recently edited row. I would prefer if I would not have to send the object through all the controller methods used to reload the page.

Thanks for the help, appreciate it!

Comment: Can you post the content returned by "controllerMethodReturningEditView"?

Comment: I have another question regarding datatables here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447735/mvc3-getting-values-from-edited-rows-in-datatable if anyone would like to help me out there aswell. Really appreciate your help guys!

Comment: For your data that is being returned, is there a datetime record for the last modified?

Comment: Nope and it is not needed either. It is just supposed to be a temporary thing, navigate away from that page and go back and it will be forgoten

Comment: Since you are refreshing the page rather than doing an Ajax post and replacing the content, this is going to be challenging to know what has changed. If you add a hidden time-stamp with the last update time, you could then hook some JavaScript to highlight any row that has been updated in "X" seconds. If this is do-able, then I can assist with some code...

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what's being returned to the page and not knowing the styling you want to update.

Let's say you want to alternate each rows css class. You could do something like below after the content is added to the page:

```
$("tr:nth-child(odd)", "#YOUR_TABLE_ID").addClass("odd-row");
```

Or, make sure that each rows HTML is formatted it an unique ID tag "..." and then do some jQuery do set the class after being added to the page.

If the request is an Ajax request, and you're returning something back using json - like:

```
var json { Id = Table.ID, status = true };
```

Then the OnSuccess event would do something like this:

```
function OnSaveSuccess(data) {
    if (data.status) {
        $("#" + data.Id).addClass("highlight-row");
    } else {
    console.warn("save was not successful!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you missunderstand my question. I want to edit a row in the table -> update the object by sending the changes to the database -> reload the page and putting a red border on the row containing the object information that was just edited so the user can verify his/hers changes. Everything is working today except for the part where the row gets a red border around itself, and that's what I need help with

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarifying. I'm not sure what you're returning, but I've updated the example as if you were returning json.

Comment: I'm not returning a json object. See the site is constantly working with a database, and everytjme a view is loaded data is requested from backend (wcf) which gets the data from the database. See my question for an update and thank you for trying to help me :)